# Gnome/Gtk equivalent of KeePassX?

Tags: linux, passwords, gnome, password-management, gtk

KeePassX is a great password storing program, but it doesn't use Gtk and doesn't integrate well at all with Gnome. Is there an equivalent program designed for Gnome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Revelation](https://github.com/mikelolasagasti/revelation).

Update: last commit was in 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Try [gnome-keyring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Keyring).  It's the standard for gnome in every distro I've ever used and integrates seamlessly.

Comment: Except it doesn't let you to add your own password entries (at least Seahorse, the default GUI, doesn't)

Comment: I'm aware that this is very old now, but for anyone stumbling on this answer after googling for a GTK3+ password manager, Seahorse does now let you create your own keyrings, add passwords, etc. using gnome-keyring.